# Fail to call/ map to servlet from index.html via web.xml - error - 404

Tags: jsp, servlets, http-status-code-404

```
    I am creating a simple servlet on spring tool set / eclips but am failing to run it. on running 
    the project, i am able to see my index home page html and click on the link for my jsp but fail
    to get to the servlet link. i have attached the web.xml file which has the paths. i am 
    confused 

              1. what should i put  in servlet-name 
              2. what should i put  in servlet-class  
              3. what should i put  in url-patter 
              4. Is there is any relation between the index.html file and web.xml file.
              5. Finally what is my servlet-class supposed to hold?
```

**My index.html holds:
====================**

```
<ul>
          <li>To a <a href="HellBoy.jsp">JSP page</a>.
          <li>To a <a href="/HellBoy">HelloWorldServlet</a>.
      </ul>
```

**My web.xml holds:
=================**

```
  <servlet>  
    <servlet-name>HellBoyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.ravi.servlet.HellBoy</servlet-class>
 </servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HellBoServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Hell</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
    -----------------------------------------
```

- The servlet itself is in src/com.ravi.servlet/ directory and called
  HellBoy.java
- On running, i see my index page but i can only successfully click on
  href="HellBoy.jsp"
         The link to servlet, href="/HellBoy" ---- F A I L S --- giving error -- HTTP Status 404 -
         /HellBoy/Hell
- Sorry for a silly question but i have been scouring the web for a
  solution for the whole week :(

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to make entry in web.xml like this

```
      <servlet>
        <description> desc</description>
        <display-name>HelloBoy</display-name>
        <servlet-name>HelloBoy</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.abc.xyz.HelloBoy</servlet-class>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloBoy</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/HelloBoy</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
```

and if you use eclipse for your IDE then directly create new servlet, it will automatically make all entry in web.xml

Answer (score 0):

The URL of the servlet should be http://{host}/{appname}/Hell.

if you want to link your servlet access from /HellBoy http://{host}/{appname}/HellBoy, you should

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HellBoServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/HellBoy</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I tried changing the url-pattern to HellBoy but that too did work - i just learnt that i had given the slash/ in index.html, which was also supposed to be just HellBoy, so you were right about what i needed to do in the web.xml but i also needed to do the no slash in the index.html - but thanks so much tom87416 cause you got me thinking right - appreciated

Comment: i also larnt that in the servlet i had an anotation (its a new feature i hear ) which was also calling the servlet i had created as HellBoy and the Hell would not have worked regardless of the exact match in the index.html

Answer (score 0):

#### index.html

- Do not write `/HellBoy` in `href` attribute.
- Here give name that matches `<url-pattern>`, in this case it it `Hell`.
- Do not need to change `web.xml`.

Change to

```
<li>To a <a href="Hell">HelloWorldServlet</a>
```

---

> what should i put  in servlet-name

`<servlet-name>` must match both in `<servlet>` and `<servlet-mapping>`.

> what should i put  in servlet-class

Fully qualified name of servlet

> what should i put  in url-patter

URL pattern that you wish.

For all questions, please read carefully [The Java EE 6 Tutorial Chapter 15 Java Servlet Technology](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html)

Comment: Thanks Aniket. I was able to get it working and yes the above answers have further clarified my questions - appreciated